# String loop in T-SQL

Tags: sql, arrays, sql-server, loops

How can I do the loop in string.If I want to get number of consecutive addition equals to 1

e.g '321'  (2-1 counts as 1, 3-2 counts as 1): result 2

e.g '320244434321' (2-1 count as 1, 3-2 count as 1 and 4-3 count as 1) result is 3

e.g '00321881'(2-1 counts as 1, 3-2 counts as 1): result 2

Comment: Please clarify the question.  I cannot make sense of "number of consecutive addition equals to 1".  Also, databases are not the best tool for such string processing.

Comment: max number of consecutive time that when I subtract  the two columns its equal (from left to right) is equal to 1

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the number of adjacent digits that decrease by "1".  And you are not counting values twice.  So, you can use brute force:

```
select ( (case when str like '%10%' then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when str like '%21%' then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when str like '%32%' then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when str like '%43%' then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when str like '%54%' then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when str like '%65%' then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when str like '%76%' then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when str like '%87%' then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when str like '%98%' then 1 else 0 end)
        )
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes this is what I'm looking for. :)